# Assigning same id to 2 MySQL table rows in PDO statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble wrapping my brain around how I would do this. I just started learning about about PDO, so forgive the ignorance. I have a form that simply inserts some post data and image data into a MySQL database. I have a separate table for post data and image data. They both have a row called `postid`. The posts `postid` currently is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` I just simply need to have the same `postid` go into both images and posts tables. However, it is not quite that simple. An image will not always be added to every post. So simply having `AUTO_INCREMENT` on both to increment simultaneously would not suffice. The images `postid` just needs to always match the corresponding posts `postid`

I know this isn't a very specific question regarding a code issue, but was hoping i could get some good insight at least.

#### This is the code I currently have functioning correctly aside from adding `postid` to the `images` table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
    <div><textarea name="entry" maxlength="600"></textarea></div>
    <div><input name="userfile" type="file" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
  </form>

</body></html>


<?php
/*** check if a file was submitted ***/
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
    }
else
    {
    try    {
        upload();
        /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/
        echo '<p>Thank you for submitting</p>';
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
        }
    }
?>

<?php
//Upload function
function upload(){

/*** check if a file was uploaded ***/
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) != false)
    {
    /***  get the image info. ***/
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    /*** assign our variables ***/
    $type = $size['mime'];
    $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $size = $size[3];
    $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $maxsize = 99999999;
    $poster = $_SESSION['username'];
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];


    /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize )
        {
        /*** connect to db ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name", 'user', 'password');

                /*** set the error mode ***/
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            /***sql query ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (poster, entry) VALUES (? ,?)");

        /*** bind the params ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
        $stmt2->bindParam(1, $poster);
        $stmt2->bindParam(2, $entry);

        /*** execute the query ***/
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt2->execute();

        }
    else
        {
        /*** throw an exception is image is not of type ***/
        throw new Exception("File Size Error");
        }
    }
else
    {
    // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
    throw new Exception("Unsupported Image Format and/or to large of a file.");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Insert into one table then query for the ID before you insert to the second table. Then you have one table set to auto increment.

Comment: so before executing `stmt2` run a `select` query for the ID, then insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Execute the query that inserts the post, which creates the auto increment id.
2. Use `$dbh->lastInsertId()` to get this new id.
3. Prepare the image query and use the id you got in step 2.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (poster, entry) VALUES (?, ?)");
...
$stmt->execute();
$id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (post_id, image_type, image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (?, ? ,?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
...
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: O would I just add `$dbh->lastInsertId()` between the 2 executions?

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. Idk why I was having issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInsertId(){
        global $db;
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    }
```

I like to put this function in a file that is included such as a header or something. That way, I can always get the inserted ID. So after you do your insert post, you can call this function to get the ID of the row you just created.

Comment: You need a function wrapper for a single function call...?!

Answer (score 0):

```
    First do the posts query(stmt2) execution:

    $stmt2->execute();

    then get the postid from the previous executed query:
    $postid= $dbh->lastinsertid();

    then for saving the images to database: You need to create a column post_id in the images table , so the uploaded     image has a parent post id.

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_type ,image, 
image_size, image_name,post_id) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(5,postid);
$stmt->execute();
```